# How to make links clickable on UIAlertController text message with HTML links

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, uialertcontroller

My UIAlertController is displaying all HTML formatting fine, but the links are not clickable. The post here assumes that we know where the links are, but the text message is coming from API, hence I can't control the specific string. I'm hoping there is a universal attribute which can be assigned to UIAlertController so links become clickable. Thanks

```
let htmlText = "Some text from API with random links here and there"
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Details", message:"", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
let attributedText = htmlText.html2AttributedString
alertController.setValue(attributedText, forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

String extension **html2AttributedString** here, *but this extension is working so no need to check this part*:

```
extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8),
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIAlertController` has no public support for what you want. Your use of `setValue` is attempting to access a private API that could change in an iOS update. Best to avoid such code completely. Write or find a custom alert class that supports what you want to do.

Comment: even if there are third-party libraries I would use them if you could suggest one, please? Otherwise will need to give up the idea of UIAlertController if links are not clickable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible in the standard way, because you don't have access to the `UILabel` inside of `UIAlertController` 
in a normal `UILabel` you can add tap gesture on your `UILabel` and handle the gesture.
so here you need a custom `UIAlertController`

but I suggest you to export links from the html text and show them as an action button like this:

```
var links : [String:NSURL] = [:]
let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)
attributedText.enumerateAttribute(.link, in: range, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) {attribute, range, pointer in

    let text = attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
    if let url = attribute as? NSURL {
           links[text] = url
         }
}

links.forEach { (linkText, url) in
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: linkText, style: .default, handler: {_ in
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
                }))
}
```